# Mongo Query to filter using multiple conditions together

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

**How do you find documents with ALL value types or some value in MongoDB?**

I have some fields in the document which I want to use as filters to filter documents.

**Example:-**

**Person** field can take one of the following values:- `[Person A, Person B, Person C,....]`

**Type** field can take one of the following values:- `[Type A, Type B, Type C]`

**Source** field can take one of the following values:- `[Source A, Source B, Source C]`

I want to use the above-mentioned **fields together to filter the documents.**

The above-mentioned fields `should be filtered as All or some specific value` of the field.

**what I mean is**

- for a query, I want **all the Persons** of **Type A** of **Source B.**
- for another query, I may want **Person B** of **All Type** for **Source C.**

and so on...

**I want to use all the fields combined in the query to filter the documents.**

**How Do you achieve this in MongoDB?**

**Dataset:-**

```json
{
    "_id": "1",
    "Person": "Person A",
    "type": "Type A",
    "source": "Source A",
    "subject": "some subject"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "Person": "Person B",
    "type": "Type B",
    "source": "Source C",
    "subject": "some subject"
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "Person": "Person C",
    "type": "Type A",
    "source": "Source A",
    "subject": "some subject"
},
{
    "_id": "4",
    "Person": "Person C",
    "type": "Type C",
    "source": "Source B",
    "subject": "some subject"
},
{
    "_id": "5",
    "Person": "Person A",
    "type": "Type B",
    "source": "Source A",
    "subject": "some subject"
},
{
    "_id": "6",
    "Person": "Person B",
    "type": "Type C",
    "source": "Source A",
    "subject": "some subject"
}
```

**Example Filter Query 1:-**

**Person**: All (i.e A,B,C)

**Type**: A

**Source**: A

**Expected Output for query 1:-**

get documents with **id:-** **1 and 3**  `Coz only ids 1&3 have Type and Source as A`

**Example Filter Query 2:-**

**Person**: A

**Type**: All

**Source**: ALL

**Expected Output for query 2:-**

get documents with **id:- 1 and 5** `coz person A has documents 1 & 5 associated with him.`

**Example Filter Query 3:-**

**Person**: ALL

**Type**: All

**Source**: B

**Expected Output for query 2:-**

get documents with **id:- 4** `coz only id 4 has source as B`

Comment: Please update your question to provide some sample dataset and expected output to let us have a more concrete understandings on your problem.

Comment: @ray Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performing querying with `$eq`, you can use `$or` to "escape" the query when the param supplied is "All".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      // put your query param here
      "paramPerson": "All",
      "paramType": "Type A",
      "paramSource": "Source A"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramPerson",
                  "All"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramPerson",
                  "$Person"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "All"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "$type"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "All"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "$source"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "paramPerson": false,
      "paramSource": false,
      "paramType": false
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HxsM4Yf0roo) for your reference.